# How can I start two unicorn services at startup?

Tags: ubuntu, service, init.d

I am running both my staging and production environments on the same DigitalOcean Ubuntu box.  I have everything working so that each environment can be deployed to its own directory, run a separate unicorn process with separate pid files, and nginx is configured with separate sites-enabled files to associate each of those unicorn instances with its proper environment.

My deploy process properly (re)starts unicorn for the matching environment.  The problem is when I need to restart the box itself, in which my `/etc/init.d/unicorn` is only configured to launch for production.  I'm not sure what I need to do to make both production and staging launch at startup, shy of creating secondary `/etc/init.d/unicorn-staging` and `/etc/default/unicorn-staging` files.

Here are my existing files for reference.

## /etc/init.d/unicorn

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: unicorn initscript
# Description:       unicorn
### END INIT INFO

set -e
NAME=unicorn
DESC="Unicorn web server"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -f /etc/default/unicorn ]; then
  . /etc/default/unicorn
fi

PID=${PID-/run/unicorn.pid}

run_by_init() {
    ([ "${previous-}" ] && [ "${runlevel-}" ]) || [ "${runlevel-}" = S ]
}

exit_with_message() {
  if ! run_by_init; then
    log_action_msg "$1 Not starting."
  fi
  exit 0
}

check_config() {
  if [ $CONFIGURED != "yes" ]; then
    exit_with_message "Unicorn is not configured (see /etc/default/unicorn)."
  fi
}

check_app_root() {
  if ! [ -d $APP_ROOT ]; then
    exit_with_message "Application directory $APP_ROOT is not exist."
  fi
}

set -u

case "$1" in
  start)
        check_config
        check_app_root

        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
          ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal QUIT --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  force-stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Forcing stop of $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" $NAME || true
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID
        sleep 1
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  reopen-logs)
        log_daemon_msg "Relopening log files of $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID; then
          log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
          log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc -p $PID $DAEMON $NAME && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  *)
        log_action_msg "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|force-reload|reload|force-stop|reopen-logs|status>" || true
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

## /etc/default/unicorn

```
# Change paramentres below to appropriate values and set CONFIGURED to yes.
CONFIGURED=yes

# Default timeout until child process is killed during server upgrade,
# it has *no* relation to option "timeout" in server's config.rb.
TIMEOUT=60

# Path to your web application, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb,
# option "working_directory". Rack's config.ru is located here.
APP_ROOT=/var/www/example.com/current

# Server's config.rb, it's not a rack's config.ru
CONFIG_RB=/var/www/example.com/current/config/unicorn.rb

# Where to store PID, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb, option "pid".
PID=/var/www/coderfit.com/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c $CONFIG_RB -E production"

PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/var/www/example.com/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:$
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@example
export GEM_PATH=/var/www/example.com/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@example:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
DAEMON=/var/www/example.com/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy `/etc/init.d/unicorn` into `/etc/init.d/unicorn_app2`.

Edit `unicorn_app2` file:

- Change `/etc/default/unicorn` into `/etc/default/unicorn_app2`
- Change `/run/unicorn.pid` into `/run/unicorn_app2.pid`

Copy `/etc/default/unicorn` into `/etc/default/unicorn_app2`

Edit `/etc/default/unicorn_app2` to setup your second app

Run new server `service unicorn_app2 start`, also setup your nginx/apache for second app (with new pid file)